# Android activity class gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

**My problem is that one specific activity in my app can't be launched for some reason, and it throws:**

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference`

All other launching code that looks like this work fine, the problem is ONLY when I'm launching `Player1`. The class surely exists, and I can't understand what is the problem.

I'm launching an activity called `Player1` from an activity called `ChooseLevel`. When some button is pressed, the call is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseLevel.this, Player1.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("game_level", 1);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

The logs show that the error is in: `Player1.onCreate(Player1.java:50)`

The code in line `Player1:50` is:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player1);

    changeIndex = 0;
    cards = new ArrayList<Card>(8);
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_text);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_text);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    timer.setText(String.valueOf(definitions.TIMER_START)); # LINE 50

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    ... 
}
```

When this launching code runs, I get this in my logs:

```
33:04.338 18302-18302/com... D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-18 10:33:04.338 18302-18302/com... E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
           Process: com..., PID: 18302
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.../com....Player1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at com....Player1.onCreate(Player1.java:50)
```

**EDIT:**

**I found my answer,** it had to do with some object that I had in my `Player1.onCreate()` method. In a wierd way, android-studio raised the exception regarding `getClass()`. **If someone knows why this happend,** please share :)

Comment: `Player1.onCreate(Player1.java:50)` - That number is the line number where the Exception happens. Look on line 50. Btw, if you'd gone through the answers in the suggested duplicate, you would know that.

Comment: You're not showing the line throwing the exception.

Comment: Check Your Manifest file , have you declare Player1 in Manifest ?

Comment: The line throwing the exception is showed, I copied the beginning of the onCreate function. @h_patel Yes, I checked it now.

Comment: @GhostCat Please explain why it is a duplicate, I can't understand why and I don't get my answer from the regular answer.

Comment: @OferArial : just make sure that you timer is addressing to the right id in right layout and then if so, try to clean your project and try once again.

Answer (score 0):

use context,getApplicationContext()`or`getActivity()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Player1.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("game_level", 1);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Erm, no, that is not what you should do